# How to make the toolbar transparent when the keyboard is active

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, toolbar, android-toolbar

When I click on the edit-texts and the keyboard show, but the toolbar becomes white..!! I want it to become transparent and show the logo beneath it..!?

here's What I tried and it didn't work so far..

---

I set the background color of the toolbar to a white color name "transparent" with opacity= 0

```
mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
```

tried it from xml but didn't work also..

[My Problem, see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FbxD.png)

---

replace the previous line with this, it causes a null-pointer exception

```
  mToolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

here's the error, and it doesn't make any sense since there IS a reference and if i set any property for the toolbar.. no error shows..!? just the Alpha that causes this.!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setAlpha(int)' on a null object reference
```

---

is there a way that I can hide the toolbar when the keyboard shows..!? tried to do it but can't figure out how..!?

---

**CODE**

**BaseActivity**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Toolbar mToolbar;
protected String title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    Toolbar(mToolbar);

}

public void Toolbar(Toolbar toolbar) {
    toolbar.setTitle(this.title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

**MY Login Activity extends BaseActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    this.title = getString(R.string.action_sign_in);
    /* causes a crash */ this.mToolbar.getBackground().setAlpha((int)(0.01) * 255);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // other code ....
   }
```

Comment: post your full code...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I did, check out it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Activity`, if you are using `AppCompatActivity`, you can set `Toolbar` background like this way-

```
     Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
     mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,android.R.color.transparent));
```

This works perfectly in my project.

From `xml`,
you can set your toolbar background like this way

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

This two methods working well in my project. I think it will work in your case as well.

Comment: when I add your last line below my onCreate in LoginActivity, nothing changes.!?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this float ratio below to make toolbar transparent.

```
mToolbar.getBackground().setAlpha((int)(myFloatValue) * 255);
```

Comment: It causes a crash see the code I added, notice the comment

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable()` instead of `mToolbar.setBackgroundColor()` and `mToolbar.getBackground().setAlpha()`

**Try this:**

```
..........
.....................
// Change color
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.transparent)));

..............
........................
```

**You can also use:**

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xffFF0000)); // RED color
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))); // RED color
```

Comment: I tried all of these, but no luck,,, can you please take  a look at the code above, and see where is the best position in the LoignActivity it should be put..!? 

I placed it below the OnCreate and it didn't work!